# Replace text in HTML tag. Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Do you know if it is possible to replace the text inside a tag for another tag?

For example. In this case:

```
 <td style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;line-height:10px; width:37px;">--</td>
```

I am trying to scrap the info inside "td" tags and tagged with "span", but some cases does not have the tag "span" which is the one I am looking for to scrap. I would like to replace the string "--" inside "td" tag for:

```
 <span class="something"></span>
```

getting something like this:

```
   <td style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;line-height:10px; width:37px;"> <span class="something"></span></td>
```

I saw is possible to replace one tag for another but I dont know if this is possible or how to do it

Comment: Hey, your question is not clear what you want to do?

Comment: Hi. I edited the question. Thats what I would like to get. Replace the "--" text inside td tag for all that span tag written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your intention is unclear, by using simple jQuery you can achieve the effect.

```
$('td').html("<span class='something'></span>");
```

If what you want is to put everything inside `td` into a new `span`,

```
var currentText = $('td').html();
$('td').html("<span class='something'>" + currentText +"</span>");
```

This will transform

```
<td style="...">Hello</td>
```

into

```
<td style="..."><span class="something">Hello</span></td>
```

Hope you got your answer.

---

#### Edit:

This example is for a scenario where you have `td` elements both with and without `span` elements inside. This code checks if there any direct child `span` inside `td` before modifying it.

```
$("td").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).find('> span').length == 0){
        var currentText = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("<span class='something'>" + currentText +"</span>");
    }
});
```

In python, use `pyquery` package or equivalent to manipulate html / xml and achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes. The result I want is that. What I forgot to say is that some TD tags already have SPAN inside. So I just want to insert SPAN in those which dont have it (That TD tags have that "--" text inside, instead of SPAN

Comment: Ok I will improve the answer.

Comment: I will try this, but I have never used JQuery in pyhton. Is just a library and use the functions, right?

Comment: yes, use `pyquery`, although I used original jQuery to show you the method, you can do the same manipulations in `pyquery` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;line-height:10px; width:37px;">--</td>
```

Add id in this TD tag and then

```
document.getElementById("td_id").innerHTML = "<span>your items</span>";
```

Comment: Yes. The result I want is that. What I forgot to say is that some TD tags already have SPAN inside. So I just want to insert SPAN in those which dont have it (That TD tags have that "--" text inside, instead of SPAN

Comment: For that you will have to make some conditions and you can manage those conditions with python or something as you are using scrappy. Check using python if something like <span> exists somewhere in that line or not